# understanding target and uses-sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-manager

I'm a newbie to Android, and I'm trying to run an existing application.

In the file project.properties I have this line:

```
target=android-20
```

While in the manifest file, I have this line:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Shouldn't these 2 directives refer to the same SDK version?
Is there any error in the app I'm trying to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the two are different things.
`minSDKVersion` specifies that the app is supported minimum from which API level.
whereas `targetSDKVersion` mentions that which `build-tool` API version to be used to build the project. Both could have any value of Android API level but `targetSDKVersion` should not be less than `minSDKVersion`. Eclipse also gives error for this.

You might have noticed: when you use library method for old API than minSDKVersion API, It will raise an error asking to change the `minSDKVersion`. And the `targetSDKVersion` you are choosing in manifest file, you should have `build-tool` of that particular API.